# Download specific version of object stored on AWS S3 with PHP SDK

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using Amazon's PHP-SDK in my symfony application to upload files (aka "objects" in s3 lingo) to a bucket that has versioning enabled. Thus when I upload a file with the same name (aka "key") multiple times the bucket retains one object of the file with multiple versions.

That's the behaviour I was going for, as I use the bucket to store (versioned) backups of the application.

Now, when I want to download the backup again, it seems like Amazon only let's me download the default object (apparently using the most recent version). I cannot find a method or example in the official documentation (or anywhere else for that matter) that lets me download a specific version (as in : give me that backup from last week).

Is that the expected behaviour or am I missing something here ? If that limit is inherent to s3 though, the whole point of versioning buckets is kind of absurd.

Best regards and thanks for any hints in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a two step processes. You would have to get the list of all the versions with this api call.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#listobjectversions

```
$result = $client->listObjectVersions([
    'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
]);
```

Which returns

```
  [
    'CommonPrefixes' => [
        [
            'Prefix' => '<string>',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'DeleteMarkers' => [
        [
            'IsLatest' => true || false,
            'Key' => '<string>',
            'LastModified' => <DateTime>,
            'Owner' => [
                'DisplayName' => '<string>',
                'ID' => '<string>',
            ],
            'VersionId' => '<string>',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'Delimiter' => '<string>',
    'EncodingType' => 'url',
    'IsTruncated' => true || false,
    'KeyMarker' => '<string>',
    'MaxKeys' => <integer>,
    'Name' => '<string>',
    'NextKeyMarker' => '<string>',
    'NextVersionIdMarker' => '<string>',
    'Prefix' => '<string>',
    'VersionIdMarker' => '<string>',
    'Versions' => [
        [
            'ETag' => '<string>',
            'IsLatest' => true || false,
            'Key' => '<string>',
            'LastModified' => <DateTime>,
            'Owner' => [
                'DisplayName' => '<string>',
                'ID' => '<string>',
            ],
            'Size' => <integer>,
            'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD',
            'VersionId' => '<string>',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
]
```

Then set the VersionId parameter in the GetObject api call

```
$result = $client->getObject([
    'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'VersionId' => '<string>',
]);`
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#getobject